# Bit representation and meaning of format

Tags: bit, bit-representation

I am working on a home assignment and I don't understand one thing about it.. Maybe some of you guys can help me with that.

```
(a < 0) ? 1 : -1
```

What does this mean?

Comment: Google "ternary" or "conditional" operator (I've removed an errant full stop in the code snippet).

Comment: what language? I am assuming c.

Comment: Most definitely C, yes.

Comment: So this is basically another representation of if and else-statements?

Comment: yes it is. just less instructions.

Comment: ~((a >> W) << 1) would this be equivalent ? 

Where W meaning Word size (which is 31 in this context)

Comment: those look like bit shifting operations to me.

Comment: also if this is homework, why dont you just write it in C code and see the result? that is what i used to do.

Answer (score 1):

This is basically saying is the variable a less then 0? if it is 1 if it is not then -1 it is like this

```
if(a<0)
   1
else
  -1
```